# get the last data inserted in table query

Tags: java, sql, h2

I want to get the last data inserted 5 minutes ago and with a certain status but I get `SQLException expected "., (, [, ::, *, /, %, +, -, ||, ~, !~, NOT, LIKE, REGEXP, IS, IN, BETWEEN, AND, OR, ,, )";`, here is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
WHERE (CREATE_DATE >(systimestamp - (interval '5' minute)) )AND STATUS='in progress';
```

Comment: I am not an expert, but could anyone give me a link to sql documentation where `STATUS` is used as `WHERE` condition?

Comment: Status is a field in my table, and it's working fine, thank you.

Comment: I think it is bad idea to call your fields `WHERE,SELECT, STATUS, AND   etc...` So did you get your code working? or this question is still open?

Comment: I already posted my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is :

```
CREATE_DATE > DateADD(mi, -5, Current_TimeStamp)
```